# Microsoft Power Automate: Web Browser Automation Flow: Do all the UI elements need to be recaptured in a different desktop?

Tags: power-automate, webautomation, power-automate-desktop

MS PA flow sharing is not offered for a free version but there is a work around to copy all the flows to a text, and pasting it into another desktop's PA environment.

However, for web browser automation flows, it looks like all the UI elements that the flow interacts with need to be reconfigured since it's in a different environment even though we all use the same browser, same PA version, and the same flow code.

For example, one step of the flow focuses the window on the current Google Chrome instance. Although there's no local specific settings configured, this step will not pass on another desktop, meaning all flows relating to UI elements must be reassigned.

We don't mind switching to premium versions but I'm worried that this issue is going to remain and all the users that have the flow shared needs to reconfigure every single UI element again.

Please let me know if...

1. this is something that's easily handled.
2. completely removed if we switch to a paid version.
3. there's any other work around.

Thank you in advance!